# Gstreamer Ndk-build Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

i want to use gstreamer on my android phone , but i got these errors when i run ndk-build , though i have alread add -pthread .

anyone know how to fix this , i built this on my ubuntu computer

- Android.mk

  ```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  LOCAL_MODULE    := test_lib
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test_gst.cpp
  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -pthread
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
  ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
  $(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
  endif
  GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
  endif
  GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build

  include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
  ```
- Error

  ```
  The list of GSTREAMER_PLUGINS is empty"
  GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
  GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
  GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so
  gstinfo.c:1885: error: undefined reference to 'dladdr'
  gwakeup.c:146: error: undefined reference to 'eventfd'
  glib-unix.c:98: error: undefined reference to 'pipe2'
  gthread-posix.c:444: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_init'
  gthread-posix.c:453: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_destroy'
  gthread-posix.c:652: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_condattr_init'
  gthread-posix.c:669: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_condattr_destroy'
  gthread-posix.c:453: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_destroy'
  gthread-posix.c:543: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
  gthread-posix.c:561: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_trywrlock'
  gthread-posix.c:581: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock'
  gthread-posix.c:600: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
  gthread-posix.c:618: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock'
  gthread-posix.c:638: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock'
  ./bindtextdom.c:312: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock'
  ./bindtextdom.c:91: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
  ./bindtextdom.c:91: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
  ./loadmsgcat.c:1287: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_init'
  ./textdomain.c:73: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
  ./textdomain.c:117: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock'
  ./dcigettext.c:1016: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
  ./dcigettext.c:530: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
  ./finddomain.c:87: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_armeabi-v7a] Error 1
  ```

- solution :

  ```
  android update project --name testing_2 --target 1 --path  /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/testing_2/app/src/main/
  ```

---

- Error (when i run android app on my phone)

  ```
  E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.flowenol.testing_2-47/libtest_lib.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so" needed by "libtest_lib.so"; caused by library "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so" not found
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.flowenol.testing_2, PID: 21833
  E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so" needed by "libtest_lib.so"; caused by library "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so" not found
  ```

but i saw the libgstreamer_android.so is in that folder
than i try to System.loadlibrary("gstreamer_android") before i load libtest_lib

than i got these :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.flowenol.testing_2, PID: 20447
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/freedesktop/gstreamer/GStreamer
```

Comment: See http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gstreamer-android-1-2-0-ndk-build-error-undefined-reference-to-xx-td4663186.html, you too may have missed **android update …**

Comment: thanks alex , i fix the error by   android update   , but i got an error when i run the android app ...

Comment: You should write loadLibrary("gstreamer_android"), without lib prefix

Comment: i know , i just forget when i write here , but i write System.loadLibrary("gstreamer_android");  in my code ...

Comment: thanks alex , i fix it by copy  [ org/freedesktop/gstreamer/GStreamer.java] to [ main / java ]